# Proofing Convergence of Cauchy Sequence in Metric Space with Cluster Point

Tags: analysis

Prove that if a Cauchy sequence in a metric space (not assumed to be complete) has a limit point, then it has a limit.

My idea is using Cauchy sequence definition and limit point definition to proof convergence but having difficulties on writing it.